# Plotting 2-variable Function with integration using MatLab

Tags: matlab, plot

Does anyone have an example of how to plot a 2-variable function with integration in MatLab (without using MuPAD)?

Here is what I've got:

```
clear all;

%define a, p and w

a=1;
p=1;
w=5;

%calculate xmin and xmax

xmin=a-p/2
xmax=a+p/2

%define the coordinates 


x=linspace(xmin,xmax);
y=linspace(0,1);

%define the coordinates along x-y plane

[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);

%define and compute the given function along the x-y coordinates

z=w-(1/p)*int((x.-y)^2, x, xamin, xmax) ;

figure
surf(y,x,z)
title ('a=1 and p=1');
xlabel('w')
ylabel('t')
zlabel('x')
axis tight
shading interp
colorbar
```

Clearly, there is something wrong with my function z. The function is

z=w-(1/p)*int(x-t)^2dx where x ranges from a-p/2 to a+p/2

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Your function

```
z=w-(1/p)*int((x.-y)^2, x, xamin, xmax) ;
```

does not depend on x, since

```
 >> syms x y xmin xmax
 >> func = int((x-y)^2,x,xmin,xmax)

 func =

 xmax*(y^2 + xmax*(xmax/3 - y)) - xmin*(y^2 + xmin*(xmin/3 - y))
```

so doing a surface plot is not needed, a simple plot is sufficient.
You can do this with

```
z = xmax*(y.^2 + xmax*(xmax/3 - y)) - xmin*(y.^2 + xmin*(xmin/3 - y));
plot (y ,z);
```

before converting x and y to a grid via meshgrid:

[image]

Comment: Of course, you are right. The next step is to vary w. I just assumed for this example that w is fixed.

Comment: Okay, then just use the function i gave with meshgrids x,y like `z = w-(1/p)* ( xmax*(y.^2 + xmax*(xmax/3 - y)) - xmin*(y.^2 + xmin*(xmin/3 - y)))`
(and put in your w, the integral still does not depend on w)